# Is there a way to programmatically add text from one word file to another?

Tags: python, ms-word

I've tried using python's mailmerge library on MS Word fields, but I lose all the formatting on the text. I'm wondering if there's a way to replicate going in Word and using 'Insert>Object>Text from file' using a python library (or really anything at this point). If there's an easy way to do this by editing the oxml even that would work. I just need some idea of where to start looking, or if I need to program this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with something to start with, hope it is useful. In the code below, I do open the file or create one if it does not exist, write some lines of data. Read the same lines of data in file1 then write them in a freshly created file2.

```
#Read and write files using the built-in Python methods
def main():
    #open the file for writing and create if it does not exist
    file = open("file1.txt", "w+")
    #write some lines of data to the file
    for i in range(5):
        file.write("This is Andela %d\r\n" % (i + 1))
    file.close()
    #write text in file1.txt to another file called file2
    open("file2.txt", "w").writelines([l for l in open("file1.txt").readlines() if "Andela" in l])

main()
```

Comment: This works for text files, but unfortunately docx files are huge collections of xml files zipped together, so I can't just use python's built in functions without a lot more hassle.

Thank you for the reply though!